# What can I do if I don't agree with an edit made to a question by a high-rep user?

Tags: discussion, edits, review

On this question, [Build a list with JSON and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768813/build-a-list-whit-json-and-jquery), even though the poster's original presentation may not have been the most helpful, I don't agree with the editor arbitrarily deciding that the OP wanted `div`s. I don't see anywhere where he said anything of that sort.

The editor obviously has more rep than me so I don't feel comfortable just reverting his edits, but I feel like I should. **What can I do?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was actually in the [original revision text](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1a43a94d-782a-4a30-9be6-c1d9f7ef444e/view-source), but SO strips out certain HTML tags for safety reasons.

Comment: I see, how can I get the revision hash?

Comment: @citizen On the post, click "edited xx mins ago", then click `source` on the header for the revision you want to see.

Comment: @citizen: You'll also see the original text exactly as the user entered it when you click the "edit" link. This is presumably what the original editor did, noticed that there was unescaped HTML code, and formatted it properly.